# Cannot Create mbuf pool with dpdk

Tags: dpdk, huge-pages

all
I tried to run vhost app in examples/, and facing the issue below:

[]# examples/vhost/build/app/vhost-switch -l 0-3 -n 4 -- --socket-file /tmp/sock0 --client -p 0x1 --stats 20
EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/.rte_unix
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: WARNING: Master core has no memory on local socket!
EAL: PCI device 0000:07:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:07:00.1 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:09:00.0 on NUMA socket -1
EAL:   Invalid NUMA socket, default to 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10d3 net_e1000_em
VHOST_PORT:
Specified port number(1) exceeds total system port number(0)
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Cannot create mbuf pool

The HugePage information is like this:

[]# sudo cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:   3129344 kB
HugePages_Total:    4096
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

I tried to run other apps, helloworld goes well, but ptpclient has the same problem. Rebooting is not help. How can I fix it?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue is here:

> Specified port number(1) exceeds total system port number(0)

This means no ethernet ports has been detected. Please make sure you have bound at least one ethernet device to the UIO or VFIO driver as described in the DPDK Getting Started Guide:

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html#binding-and-unbinding-network-ports-to-from-the-kernel-modules

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply. Two net device were bounded to dpdk, but the info is still printed.However, it runs successfully.  Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver  
============================================  
0000:07:00.1 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' drv=igb_uio unused=igb 
 0000:09:00.0 '82574L Gigabit Network Connection 10d3' drv=igb_uio unused=e1000e